# GoogleMaps API V3 for Flex/AS3

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps-api-3

Currently I am using SWC to display google map in my flex application. But now Google Maps API for Flash has been officially deprecated. The google maps web page suggests "We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API". Can someone please help me understand this?

Does that mean that I have to use java script API and load html inside flex application?

Comment: I guess that's what it suggest (although I don't know about flex). Maybe check this as well: http://openscales.org/

Comment: Does their feed allow JSON? If so - reinterpreting the data format might be the only thing you need to work on (provided you have access to the source consumer or know what that original data format looks like.

Comment: Don't go that way, switch to OSM: https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/sample-code/openstreetmap.htm

Comment: The ArcGIS API for Flex has been retired. There will be no further updates to the product or its documentation. We recommend exploring solutions built with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.
Also - MapQuest is Retiring in 2 months from now.
AIR apps don't seem to have any more native options.